# Creating a table from a mysql query and charting

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-apps-script, google-visualization

The ultimate goal I have is to take user inputs in my Appsheet app, trigger an Apps Script function to run a MySQL query using those inputs, ***chart the results of that query***, and upload that chart to my drive wherein my app can grab that drive url and display the image in a dashboard.

I have been working on this in bits and pieces and have most steps done. Yet, I am stuck on the charting the results of a query (hence it is bolded and italicized above). Without making it complicated I have a simple query and want to see how to chart it. Example code below:

```
function useDB(){
var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://my_connection_name","user","password");
 const stmt = conn.createStatement();
 let query = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM my_table');
 let arr=[];
 while(query.next()){
  arr.push([
    query.getString(1),
    query.getfloat(2)
  ]);
}
Logger.log(arr)
}
```

Now I thought this would work well as it prints an array of row values example:
`[[Hello, 3], [World, 7]]`

When researching, I saw the Google Charts Tools primarily [Charts.newDataTable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-table-builder). However, I noticed that the example given only has the function `.addRow()` where you proceed to add a singe row at a time manually. Example code I am referring to:

```
var data = Charts.newDataTable()
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Month")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "In Store")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Online")
    .addRow(["January", 10, 1])
    .addRow(["February", 12, 1])
    .addRow(["March", 20, 2])
    .addRow(["April", 25, 3])
    .addRow(["May", 30, 4])
    .build();
```

I am wondering if I can loop the `.addRow` over my array to generate the table from my query so I can go ahead and chart it. Any help or thoughts if this is possible is much appreciated. And if this is not possible or there is another way to do this altogether (like using Apps Script to utilize google visualization), I am wide open to suggestions and happy to explore them on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to get some help and found the answer to be:

```
var data = Charts.newDataTable()
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "column_1_name")
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "column_2_name");

arr.forEach(row =>
{data.addRow(row)});
data.build();
```

running this allowed me to build the table I needed and complete my process

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).